# how to hybrid online and offline database in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way that to hybrid online/offline mode can be implemented with SQL Server 2005 and an Access Frontend. Is there a way that any changes the users makes in the offline tables can be synchronized back to the server once the user is back online?

Answer (score 0):

During the Offline, you can store the data in the xml file, which nodes are similar to table schema, when you go online, make it synchronize and store changes in the database